# Facing issue for writing junit test case for the below method.Kindly let me know any suggestions how to mock below jdbc save method in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Below is the java code which need to mock using juint mockito framework it is having `@FunctionalInterface public interface PreparedStatementSetter` we also need to be mock.

```java
public boolean saveObject(ContentObject contentObject) {
        int result = 0;

        try {
            result = getJdbcTemplateWriter().update(PostgresConstants.SAVE_OBJECTS,
                    new PreparedStatementSetter() {
                        @Override
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preStmt) throws SQLException {

                            preStmt.setString(1,
                                    (contentObject.getId() != null)
                                            ? contentObject.getId().trim()
                                            : contentObject.getId());
                            preStmt.setString(2,
                                    (contentObject.getName() != null)
                                            ? contentObject.getName().trim()
                                            : contentObject.getName());
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ApplicationConstants.OBJECTS_FAILED_TO_SAVE, ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(ex,
                    ApplicationConstants.OBJECTS_FAILED_TO_SAVE);
        }

        return result > 0;
    }
```

Comment: But you **don't** need to mock `PreparedStatementSetter`. It wouldn't do you any good.

Comment: What is exactly you want to know?

Comment: Actually i need to mock this whole method using Juint mockito

Comment: Do you need to mock this method or you need to write the test case for this method.
If you need to mock then you can simple mock as `Mockito.when(classBean.saveObject(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true)`